# SQL Plus: Remove Empty/Blank line at the end of the text file

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'm trying to create a text file using SQL Plus. The output text file I produce  contains a blank/empty line at the start and end of the record.

sample output I get:

```
[empty line]
record1
record2
record3
record4
[empty line]
```

I have successfully omitted the first empty line using SET NEWPAGE NONE.

But, I am having a hard time trying to find solution for the empty line at the end of record .

Can you help please.

Comment: Your table itself had those empty records?

Comment: The table has no empty records. The empty line was generateed automatically. I found same queries about this in the internet but no solution was given.

Comment: Seems, this is how the behaviour is. If you still don't want the last line, you can do it in the caller side. Are you using Unix/Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

I find that with the following set command (all of which may not be necessary they're just what I use as standard):

`set define off trims on newp none heads off echo off feed off pagesize 0 null null verify off`

plus add a 'spool off' at the end, then there is no unwanted final blank line.

Comment: Some vendor documentation to fill this out a little: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_six.htm#SQPUG523